# Finding the number of models with a certain attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

Hi I have a model in my database User, a user can have zero, one or many Cars. I want to find all the Users in my database with one or more Cars. At the moment I have logic that says:

```
@car_user_count
for user in Users.all do

    if user.cars.count > 0 
        @car_user_count = @car_user_count + 1

end
```

This seems like an overly complicated way of doing this. I assume there must be a way of doing something like:

```
User.where(Cars.count > 0).all.count
```

but I just can't seem to get it to work, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to find all the Users in my database with one or more Cars.

```
User.includes(:cars).where.not(cars: { id: nil })
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example try `joins` with `count`:

```
User.joins(:cars).distinct.count
```

Comment: This is wrong in a way, that it won't return a number of `User` objects, but a number of `Car` objects, that are associated with at least single user